# Giving many DIVs margin-left is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a jquery based gantt chart thing and I've run into a problem. The gantt chart can be used to display fairly massive projects (100 to 500 tasks). The bars for the gantt charts are held in DIVs. Giving `500` DIVs margin is pretty slow. I've done some thinking/testing and it seems that wrapping all of the DIVs and then giving that containing DIV margin works much faster.

Current structure (simplified):

```
<tr class="task-row">
  <td>Task Name</td>
  <td><div class="gantt-bar"></div></td>
</tr>
```

The only way I can move all of the gantt bars is by selecting them all and then adding margin.

```
$(".gantt-bar").css("margin-left", "+=24px");
```

Proposed structure (simplified):

```
<div>
   <div class="left-panel">
        <div>Project Name</div>
   </div>
   <div class="right-panel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="gantt-bar"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In this case, moving the container DIV will be faster.

```
$(".container").css("margin-left", "+=24px");
```

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/cvJqP/2/

That fiddle is telling me that it should work. The reason I'm asking this question and not implementing is that the whole thing is being done with a table at the moment, and changing it to work with DIVs is quite a large task. Just trying to make sure that this will actually work before I go about doing it.

Is this the best solution to the problem? Is there a way of keeping the table implementation?

Thanks.

SOLUTION USED:

```
<tr class="task-row">
      <td>Task Name</td>
      <td><div class="base"><div class="gantt-bar"></div></div></td>
</tr>

var newmargin = parseInt($(".base:first-child").css("margin-left").replace("px", "")) + 24 + "px";
$(bars).css('margin-left', newmargin);
```

This is faster because the margin doesn't have to be re-calculated for every DIV.

Comment: Could you display the portion of your markup that is concerned?

Comment: Data belongs in tables. Why the switch?

Comment: Editing now to make it more clear.

Comment: @isherwood it's not really that kind of data. He's basically drawing a picture, and so if you're worried about semantics it's wrong either way :)

Comment: You should think over the approach to only have the elements in the dom that are really visible. This is e.g. done for performant scrolling of huge list. It does not really make sense to have `500` divs and move them if just e.g. `50` are visible. Additionally `position: absolute` could be faster then using `margin` because there   will be less dependencies.

Comment: It's not semantics if you're concerned about accessibility. Visually impaired users would probably appreciate being able to navigate a table rather than a mound of divs.

Comment: @isherwood have you looked at the fiddle?  The `<div>` elements are used as colored boxes. I agree that accessibility is important, but in this case there are some fundamental problems with that anyway.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to switch to divs instead of a table? It doesn't make sense to change everything if the current solutions works.

Comment: @jaq316 there are many reasons to change something that currently works. (Better maintainability, future-proofed concept, better user experiance or accessibility, ....). But yes it would be important to know why the new _solution_ is preferred over the current one.

Comment: @Everyone Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but the new solution is better because it's means I can move the DIVs faster. Take a look at the fiddle, you'll notice the difference in speed (if you don't add more divs with the for loop).

Comment: Totally sidebar, but `d3.js` (data driven approach) could be an alternative.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not concerned with accessibility since I know who will be using this.

Comment: @Pointy Can you think of a better way of making a gantt chart with HTML? These are the only ways that I've been able to think of to do it.

Comment: @user2538011 it's probably a fine way to do it. I guess you could get fancy and use SVG, but if you're looking for something simple and practical (and given what Gantt charts look like) simple HTML elements seem pretty good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the assignement of 1000 margins that is slow, it's the detection and calculating of the margin values for every element.

Try to detect only the values for the first-child, then aply them with somehing like this:

```
$(".r-many").click(function() {
    var oldval=$(".bar:first-child").css('margin-left').replace('px', '');
    newval=parseInt(oldval)+24+'px';
$(".bar").css('margin-left', newval);  
});
```

Here is lightning-fast fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sQHCY/

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: One problem with this. Not all of the bars will have the same margin-left, so the new margin of each element must be calculated. My example wasn't exactly clear about that, take a look at this one. http://jsfiddle.net/sQHCY/1/

Comment: Thanks. Although the answer isn't exactly what I need, you gave me an idea of how to fix it. Instead of restructuring the whole thing I can just wrap the existing divs with more divs, and then give those new divs 1 margin, instead of having to calculate a new margin for each div.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your table implementation looks like but couldn't you just add margin-left to the table instead? If not you could always wrap the table with a container and do the same as your example.

It completely makes sense to wrap all the DIVs in a container and apply the margin-left to that container.

Comment: I've edited the question, please take a look. I can't wrap the table since the bars of the chart are inside a <td> of the table.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd look into a tried and tested jquery plugin like [jQuery.Gantt](http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/).

More often than not, these plugins have resolved much of the issues you will encounter along the way.

Comment: I've looked at it but it just doesn't do what I need it to do, so I wrote my own. It's 100% complete, using tables, but with large projects open, moving the bars is slow/unresponsive. I'm trying to decide if changing everything to DIVs is a good idea.